# Deploy Laravel application

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, shared-hosting

I have uploaded my Laravel application to server (I'm using shared hosting).

Directory structure is like this:

```
--public_html
  --laravelApp
    -- app
    -- bootstrap
    -- public
    -- vendor
    -- other Laravel files
```

My document root is pointing to laravelApp/public.

When I try to access my website using laravelapp.com, I got `500`. I got same error if I try to access laravelapp.com/public or laravelapp.com/public/index.php. I don't have .htacess in root of laravelApp, just in `public` folder.

I guess it's something with .htaccess, but I'm not sure where to look. Here's how it looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I see some answers, that I should put everything (except `public` on same level as public_html), but I don't get it, why is that required.

Can someone put more light on this, why and how this should be done properly? Are there some security issues, etc?

Comment: Do you have access to your virtual host config file? Or are you using plesk or cpanel?

Comment: You definitely don't need to change the directory structure. Have you tried `laravelapp.com/index.php` ?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, yes, that was my thought as well, I'm not sure why these people change structure. Yes, I tried that, and it's 500 as well.

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/laravelApp/public/
<Directory "/var/www/public_html/laravelApp/public">
AllowOverride all
</Directory>  sorry, will be bad to read, but do you have these entries/settings? Espacially the part within the <directory> part might be interesting

Comment: @baao, hm, but I don't think I can access virtual host config file in CPanel. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that, I don't use cpanel. But I'm quite sure that you can set those directory directives anywhere. I did only 2 laravel deployments so far, but I had the same 500 error and after adding the directory directive written above everything worked fine...

Comment: yes, similar thing I'm doing when locally create virtual host. I tried to place it in .htacess, but without success, 500 again.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the "Network" tab in your browser's Developer Tools? Sometimes you can get more detail (perhaps a hint) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to set Directory to my public folder, and to add RewriteBase rule to .htaccess. Also check whethere your php version is >= 5.4.

Comment: I was in similar situation and just rename 'public' folder in 'public_html', and it work. Try it for next project, it easier than editing .htaccess